# Error while run the pipeline for D365 CRM plugin in Azure DevOps

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, dynamics-crm

Trying to import and export the plugin solution of D365 crm from one environment to another. For that I am using Azure DevOps CI/CD pipeline. I have set up the pipeline by using

1. Power DevOps Tool Installer
2. Export Solution
3. Publish build artifacts

In export solution, I have provided the connection string in the below format:

```
AuthType=Office365;Username=avijit_pp@XXXX.biz;Password=XXXXX@143;Url=https://org4db615ef.crm8.dynamics.com/
```

while I try to run the pipeline I am getting the following error:

> Couldn't connect to CRM instance after 3 attempts: Unable to connect to CRM: ID3007: The element 'pp' with namespace 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/Passport/SoapServices/SOAPFault' is unrecognized. Unable to Login to Dynamics CRM Unable to Login to Dynamics CRM

[image: error_ss]

Comment: Office365 authentication is deprecated.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But, I am able to authenticate from console application using plugin with the same credential.

Please provide some reference how to implement CI/CD for plugin development. It will be very helpful.

Thanks 
Avijit